# How to fix defects on the lower jaw? (Fill Holes in a Mesh)

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm trying to prepare the lower part of the skull that I took from the tomography image for 3d printer in blender.

I saw some defects as seen in the picture. How can I fix these defects?

This is the image I am working on.

[image]

Defects.

[image]

Comment: hello, are they holes? in that case you can boolean small objects then sculpt a bit

Comment: @moonboots Yes holes. How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tools to fill the holes like:

- Select all in *Edit* mode and *Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes* (increase the *Sides* value in the *Operator* box if necessary)
- Or Switch to *Edge* select, don't select anything and *Select > Select All By Trait > Non Manifold* and <kbd>F</kbd> to fill.
- Or, let's say that you have your object with holes (1). You can create a second object that looks like a small flatten sphere (2):

[image]

Give your object a *Boolean* modifier, *Union* mode, with the small sphere as boolean *Object*. Apply the modifier:

[image]

Then sculpt to smooth the surface (use the default sculpt brush, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to smooth):

[image]